# No installed certificates on debian:buster docker image?

Tags: docker, ssl, debian, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am following [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97244/list-all-available-ssl-ca-certificates) guidelines in a way to find what ca-certificates are out of the box installed on `debian:buster` docker image.

However it turns out the file with the corresponding information is not there.

```
▶ docker run -it debian:buster  bash
root@0259e94be9c4:/# awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '
>     /BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
bash: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: No such file or directory
root@0259e94be9c4:/#
```

Does `debian:buster` come with no preinstalled certs at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Package "ca-certificates" is not installed in the docker image you need to install it at first:

```
apt-get install -y ca-certificates
```

then you can find the cert in :

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```